# Data querying, searching and filtering - DynamoDB & Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

While playing with AWS Amplify, I was looking for the most appropriate architecture pattern, which would allow me to have the following:

1. scalable and reliable DB to handle CRUD operations (DynamoDB rocks here)
2. complex querying and filtering, where data access patterns are not strictly defined or unknown (Elasticsearch wins here)

So obviously I am hooked by the idea of streaming DynamoDB data to Elasticsearch for queries and keeping DynamoDB with read/write operations only.

[image: architecture]

What are the pros and cons of this architecture?

[**UPDATE**] Here is an example of a use case:

1. Case Management application: 2-5 core tables with information about cases and tasks, 30-50 fields per table, up to 1mil records each.
2. Users need to be able to run complex queries agains ALL fields and tables, so it's hard to pre-define specific access patterns.
3. The idea is to stream ALL data from DynamoDB to Elasticsearch, so ALL of the QUERIES goto Elasticsearch.
4. All of the read/write operations would goto DynamoDB as a primary source of data.

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676659/best-way-to-send-data-from-dynamodb-to-amazon-elasticsearch

Comment: Streaming from DynamoDB to Elasticsearch is not a problem at all. The question is whether the overall approach (**keep DynamoDB with CRUD only + send all queries to Elasticsearch**) is a good or bad practice.

Comment: Leveraging a given tech for what it does best is almost always a good idea. In your case, whether it's good or bad depends on a whole lot of things, and it starts with the use case(s) you want to solve/support. You'll need to explain a bit more in order for people to understand what you're trying to achieve and whether this architecture would fit the purpose or not.

Comment: just posted a few details about a use case

Comment: Thanks for the precisions. Are the users who CRUD the same who also search? And if that's the case, what's their expectations in terms of data availability in ES once CRUDed in DynamoDB?

Comment: Yes, they are the same users. And I would expect instant availability in Elasticseach (i'm not sure if that's possible though).

Comment: In ES itself, the latency between the time a change is done and the time that change is visible is 1 second (default refresh time). Add to that some network latency and a few other factors, and you can see that the synchronization won't be instantaneous for sure. There's going to be some latency, which your application/UI needs to account for (manage user expectations).  Are you using AWS Managed ES, vanilla ES on AWS, ES Cloud or something else?

Comment: 1 sec availability in Elasticsearch after DynamoDB CRUD transaction should not be a problem. What I'm doing right now is looking for a good prototyping toolchain, which would allow me to quickly build DB+search capabilities for business applications. I'm really excited playing with **AWS Amplify** , it allows to set up a complex DynamoDB data model and connect Elasticsearch literally in seconds (one CLI command).

Comment: ES works well if the data is in denormalized form and stored as a document without many join relations. Even join would work well up to a limit, if the workload is not write heavy. But if you happen to have highly relational data and which gets updated continuously then ES might not be a good fit. Specially rebuilding [global oridinals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_global_ordinals) would take up more and more time as the dataset size increases.